# Showing a countdown when there are less than 24 hours remaining

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

I am trying to get my countdown clock to appear only when there are less than 24 hours remaining.
I didn't write the original code. I think it should be...

`if (distance < end + ???) {`

But i'm not sure what to add ???. Here is the full code...

```
var end = new Date('05/03/2020 20:00 UTC+1');  
var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;

    // When countdown over show finished
    if (distance < 0) {

        clearInterval(timer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML =
        "Finished!";

        return;
    }

    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

// Only show countdown is less than 24 hours remains
    if (distance < end + ???) {
         // document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + ':';
          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + ' : ';
          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + ' : ';
          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + '';
      }
  }

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yvb4dahn/3/

Comment: I dont see your countdown working at all in your fiddle...

Comment: @ikiK You have to remove the `+ ???` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you change your condition to this one `if (distance < 86400000) {`. That number is 24h in milliseconds.

```js
var end = new Date('05/03/2020 10:00 UTC+1');  
var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;

    // When countdown over show finished
    if (distance < 0) {

        clearInterval(timer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML =
        "Finished!";

        return;
    }
    
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

// Only show countdown is less than 24 hours remains
 if (distance < 86400000) {
         // document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + ':';
          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + ' : ';
          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + ' : ';
          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + '';
      }
  }

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

More info about js dates and formats:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Hope it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to calculate difference in time:

```
var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = new Date('05/03/2020 20:00 UTC+1');
var secondDate = new Date();

var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate - secondDate) / oneDay));
```

This will give you result of 1.
So what you need to to is:

```
if (diffDays < 2 && diffDays > 0)
```

It will start only if one day is remaining.

```js
var end = new Date('05/03/2020 20:00 UTC+1');  
var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    
    // When countdown over show finished
    if (distance < 0) {

        clearInterval(timer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML =
        "Finished!";

        return;
    }
    
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

// Only show countdown is less than 24 hours remains


var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = new Date('05/03/2020 20:00 UTC+1');
var secondDate = new Date();

var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate - secondDate) / oneDay));
 
 if (diffDays < 2 && diffDays > 0) {
         // document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + ':';
          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + ' : ';
          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + ' : ';
          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + '';
      }
  }

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```